# Después de ocho jornadas, uno puede hacerse a la idea del "equipo tipo" que más le gusta al entrenador

Tags: gramática

¿Por qué es "[equipo](https://dle.rae.es/equipo) [tipo](https://dle.rae.es/tipo)" en la siguiente frase? Según RAE los dos términos son sustantivos, pero en este caso parece que van juntos. ¿O lo he interpretado mal? ¡Muchas gracias!

"[Después de ocho jornadas, uno puede hacerse a la idea del equipo tipo que más le gusta al entrenador](https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/hacerse-una-idea-no-es-lo-mismo-que-hacerse-a-la-idea/)"

Comment: equipo [de un]  tipo

Comment: @Lambie No. It's equipo **del** tipo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pues la respuesta no está muy lejos, puedes encontrarla en la misma [Fundeu](https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/sustantivos-en-aposicion/#:%7E:text=Una%20aposici%C3%B3n%20es%20una%20construcci%C3%B3n,invariable%20en%20cuanto%20al%20n%C3%BAmero.): se trata de una aposición

> Una **aposición** es una construcción con **dos sustantivos juntos**, el
> segundo de los cuales modifica, matiza o complementa al primero.
>
> Como se indica en la gramática académica, en este tipo de expresiones,
> solo el primer sustantivo suele llevar la marca de plural, quedando el
> segundo como invariable en cuanto al número.

En tu caso, **tipo** está actuando como si fuera un adjetivo, modificando a **equipo**. Podríamos reestructurar un poco la frase para sustituirlo. (Ojo que "hacerse a la idea" es incorrecto en ese contexto, como indica el artículo)

> Después de ocho jornadas, uno puede **hacerse una idea** de qué clase
> de equipo le gusta más al entrenador.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias de verdad por sus explicaciones!