# Clave vs Claves: Are there exceptions to adjectives being plural for describing a plural noun?

Tags: adjetivos

SpanshDict uses the following example for clave (adj):
Asegúrate de resumir los puntos clave.

Why is it not claves (plural)?

REA also says both are valid, but why? And does this fit under a broader pattern (i.e. are there other times when a plural noun can receive a singular adjective?).

Las dos opciones se pueden considerar válidas: palabras clave o palabras claves.

https://www.rae.es/duda-linguistica/es-palabras-clave-o-palabras-claves

Comment: The thing is that clave is not an adjective but a name. Here you have [aposición](https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/sustantivos-en-aposicion/#:~:text=Una%20aposici%C3%B3n%20es%20una%20construcci%C3%B3n,invariable%20en%20cuanto%20al%20n%C3%BAmero.): two names. Click in the link to know more about that.

Comment: We recently discussed another [example](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/42591/19307) of aposición

Comment: So, it's an aposición and in that case is valid. Why? I don't know. Because the RAE said so as you have already found

Comment: This is not apposition. Apposition repeats the idea: Madrid, capital de España is an apposition. Appositions require commas. And I think you mean noun, not name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write or pronounce a substantive which consists on two words written separately, you have to **determine whether the second one can only be used as substantive or if it could also be used as a adjective**. In the former situation, you can only write in plural the first word (for example: "año**s** luz", but no "*años luces"); while in the latter case both options are valid (like your example) but is more common to leave in singular the second word. You can find more information on the [RAE](https://www.rae.es/espanol-al-dia/palabras-clave-o-palabras-claves-copias-pirata-o-copias-piratas); but instead I prefer to cite the explanation of [Sipuebla forum](https://www.sipuebla.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=231), it's simpler:

> **¿los temas clave o los temas claves?**

> Ambas posibilidades son igualmente válidas. Los sustantivos compuestos formados por dos nombres separados gráficamente siguen dos modelos en la formación del plural: Si el segundo elemento, que es un modificador del núcleo, sólo tiene uso como sustantivo, la
> marca de plural se pone sólo en el primero: años luz, ciudades dormitorio, coches escoba, globos sonda, hombres lobo, hombres rana, mujeres objeto, muebles bar, operaciones retorno. En este grupo se incluyen los compuestos formados por los sustantivos macho o hembra cuando complementan a otro nombre: avestruces macho, jirafas hembra.

> ❌ El combate será entre dos pesos plumas.

> ✓ El combate será entre dos **pesos pluma**.

> ❌ Los peces espadas escasean cada vez más.

> ✓ Los **peces espada** escasean cada vez más.

> Si el segundo elemento puede usarse como adjetivo, se admite tanto la pluralización de los dos elementos como sólo la del primero: aviones espía o aviones espías, células madre o células madres, situaciones límite o situaciones límites, palabras claves o palabras clave. A este mismo grupo se adscriben los nombres compuestos de color: vestidos malvas o vestidos malva.

> ✓ A partir de la mitad la película se centra en los **temas claves**.

> ✓ A partir de la mitad la película se centra en los **temas clave**.

> ✓ Las **fechas límite** aparecen en la página electrónica.

> ✓ Las **fechas límites** aparecen en la página electrónica.

> Para saber si puede llevar marca de plural el segundo elemento, se puede intentar transformar el compuesto en una oración copulativa. Si la transformación preserva el sentido, se pueden pluralizar los dos componentes; en caso contrario, sólo el primero.

> Estos temas son claves > temas claves (o temas clave)

> Estas copias son piratas > copias piratas (o copias pirata)

> Algunas empresas son líderes > empresas líderes (o empresas líder)

> (?) Estos hombres son ranas > hombres rana (no ❌ hombres ranas)

> (?) Las ciudades son dormitorios > ciudades dormitorio (no ❌ ciudades dormitorios)

> (?) Los carriles son bicis > carriles bici (no ❌ carriles bicis)

Comment: You copied an anonymous post from an obscure forum that not even mention the word "aposición" with a strange ad-hoc rule for determining the use of plural. Did you find any other more authorizaded site where that "rule" is shown?

Comment: @RubioRic you may read [here](https://www.rae.es/espanol-al-dia/palabras-clave-o-palabras-claves-copias-pirata-o-copias-piratas) . Maybe it's true that it's not possible to say if the rule holds for all the cases. But I found the rule it's rather effective for learning. By the way, you could give a **counterexample** where the rule does not hold

Comment: Great! You can edit your post to include that reference. Even if it is mentioned in the DRAE, for me "las copias son piratas" makes no sense (are the copies sailing the seven seas drinking rum?) like the ranas and the bicis ones but both forms are valid in that case.

Comment: @RubioRic look at ngrams [https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=copias+piratas%2Ccopias+pirata&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=es-2019&smoothing=3](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=copias+piratas%2Ccopias+pirata&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=es-2019&smoothing=3) "copias piratas" is even more used than "copias pirata"; so keep trying. At least do a little more research instead of criticizing

Comment: I was not just criticizing. I was trying to improve your answer. I think that it's better now. I did some research, it's in the comments and in another post: such thing it's called aposición. I don't need to do extra research, you're the one answering. That's how this works. I don't mind that ngram, in my opinion "copias pirata" does not follow the rule, it's the counterexample that you asked for, and I wrote a sentence to back up that opinion. Are the copies sailing etc etc. In my comment I pointed out that copias piratas was perfectly valid, what should I learn from that ngram?

Comment: write a substantive? Do you mean use a  noun?? consists **of** two words